# Not always can catch SEH on WoW64 on "clean" Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, mfc, seh

I have Win32 MFC application compiled with VS2008. The application has TreeConrtol. There is a TVN_ITEMCHANGING handler and inside the handler I'm forcibly repainting the changed tree item.

Here is the code with SEH handlers and direct WinAPI calls instead of MFC wrappers (this does not affect on the issue):

```cpp
void CMainDlg::OnTvnItemChangingMainTree(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NMTVITEMCHANGE *pNMTVItemChange = reinterpret_cast(pNMHDR);

    HWND hTreeCtrl = _ctrlTree.GetSafeHwnd();
    RECT rect;
    __try
    {
        *(HTREEITEM*) &rect = hItem; 
        if ((BOOL) ::SendMessage(hTreeCtrl, TVM_GETITEMRECT, 
                (WPARAM) FALSE, (LPARAM) &rect))
        {
            ::InvalidateRect(hTreeCtrl, &rect, TRUE); 
        }
    }
    __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"SEH exception is Here", L"__except Block", MB_OK);
    }
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

If I select an item in the Tree Control (programmatically or by a mouse click), then after deleting all items from the tree control (by using DeleteAllItems or one-by-one) I'm getting the TVN_ITEMCHANGING for item which already does not exist, so the code from above leads to structured exception raising when calling ::SendMessage(hTreeCtrl, TVM_GETITEMRECT, ...).

That's OK, but... The __except block never be executed on some Windows 8.1 Pro x64 (and maybe on other Windows versions).

My working machine is English Windows 8.1 Pro x64 (build 9600) updated from Windows 8. On that machine everything works fine (the handler catches the exception and MessageBox is shown). However on a clean English Windows 8.1 Pro x64 (build 9600) downloaded from MSDN the __except block is not called and application crashes. Fault Module Name: COMCTL32.dll

I run *the same .exe file* on both computers. How do you think why this might happen?

Here is a working example. I compiled it with /EHsc and then with /EHa (the real project was compiled with /EHa and uses try/catch).

The code in the example is different from the function from above: I have added options to use try/catch and _*try/*_except.

Using /EHa I can catch the exception using both try/catch or _*try/*_except on my working machine, using /EHsc using _*try/*_except. But none of these combination works for the other machine (with clean Win8.1): it does not catch the exception.

Demo project (compiled with Visual Studio 2008 Professional SP1 + MFC): [here](http://goo.gl/AuJEDL%22).

PS: The problem has been temporarily solved by adding if condition to the SendMessage() call, but here I want to investigate the issue with exception handling.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: This is a *terrible* practice.  You can't reason about the state of your program anymore after you swallow the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You don't control all frames between the `RaiseException` (or equivalent) and the `__try/__except`: There's the `SendMessage()` call in-between.

Raymond Chen explained it best: [When you transfer control across stack frames, all the frames in between need to be in on the joke](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/09/10/10347674.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is very cognitive and explains what _may happen when you catch an exception_ but do not control all the frames in between, but it does not explain why the exception may be catched on one machine and _may not be catched_ on another one with the same Windows version and build.